# Collect & Randomize the data in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am randomizing my data(using 3 different arrays) using a function below.

```
func randomCharacter() -> String {

            let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: characters.count)

            characterImageView.image = UIImage(named: characterImages[randomNumber])

            return characters[randomNumber]

        }
```

The arrays can be seen below *(I know this may not be the best use of it, but it is something I am trying to learn)*:

```
let characters = ["Zoolog Xander"]
let characterImages = ["Zoolog Xander"]
let characterDetails = ["Knows animals well, runs like a horse, eats a hamburger in 10 seconds and smells like a cow"]
```

[image: Please see the view that contains characterLabel, ImageView and characterDetailLabel here.]

The way it is fine except the characterDetail because when you randomize the content characterLabel and ImageView matches because they use the same string but not the detail because it has a different content.

What I am planning to have a data set that can be randomized and contain all the related data with it.

I tried to put them in the following format and get a reference to it but couldn't randomize it.

```
let storyMakerCharacters = [
     ["character":"Zoolog Xander",
      "characterImage":"Zoolog Xander",
      "characterDetail":"Knows animals well, runs like a horse, eats a hamburger in 10 seconds and smells like a cow",
     ]
]
```

When I tried to use and randomize it, **randomCharacter function** did return with an error saying something like: cannot subscript [[String:String]] to Int.

What I would like to hear from you is simply either point me the right direction in terms of use of arrays in the way I want to or show me where/what I am missing in the second method. Or if you even have a better solution to such a case, that would be way much better.

---

**I updated the code as suggested but got "cannot convert return expression of type 'Character' to return type 'String'**

```
return characterArray[randomNumber]
```

This worked perfectly. The only missing part is the imageView. Title and detailText gets randomized perfectly.

```
func randomCharacter() -> Character {

            let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: characterArray.count)

            //characterImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(randomCharacter().characterImageString)")

            return characterArray[randomNumber]

}
```

I can get the values for characterName and characterDetailText fine but not the imageView. It doesn't show up on the view and get randomized.

```
characterName.text = randomCharacter().character
characterDetailText.text = randomCharacter().characterDetail
characterImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(randomCharacter().characterImageString)")
```

**ImageView does show up now because I had to change characterImageString to UIImage in the struct**

```
struct Character {
    var character: String
    var characterImage: UIImage
    var characterDetail: String
}
```

I then edited my array to reflect this:

```
var characterArray = [Character(character: "My character", characterImage: UIImage(named:"My character")!, characterDetail: "Knows animals well..."),
```

One last thing to solve is that when I randomize the data, I get different character name, image and character detail. I should be getting a data set, such Character name is Burak and the image should be the one associated with Character name and the details as well.

This is how I call the data when motionEnded. There seems to be something wrong with it. Any idea?

```
characterName.text = randomCharacter().character
characterDetailTextTrial.text = randomCharacter().characterDetail
characterImageView.image = randomCharacter().characterImage
```

Comment: Please see this post for how I sorted out what I wanted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767880/cannot-call-the-randomized-data-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment92458736_52767880

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a struct

```
Struct Character {
    var character: String
    var characterImageString: String
    var characterDetail: String
}
```

And then initialize an array with different Character's

```
var characterArray = [Character(character: "Zoolog Xander", characterImageString: "characterImageString", characterDetail: "some detail here."),
 Character(......),
 Character(......)]
```

Now you can subscript your characterArray with your random number

```
characterArray[randomNumber]
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems like I am still getting a return type error. Please see it above -at the end of the post-.

Comment: Your function randomCharacter() should not return a string but a Character (the struct object you just created).

Comment: Did you figure it out @BurakPusat ?

Comment: thanks for the help. It worked out perfect. But my only problem is that when I randomize the data, I get a different character name, character detail and an image. I added a sample code to show how I call the data when motionEnded to the actual post.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who might be interested, here is the solution I found which works as expected:

characterArray.randomElement() worked fine in the console so when shuffle it, print console shows me random Character with the details but I still couldn't figure out how to get those show up on the viewController. This is the code where I used to show on the view;

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
            if(event?.subtype == UIEvent.EventSubtype.motionShake) {


                characterArray.randomElement()
                print("\(characterArray.randomElement())")

                /*characterName.text = randomCharacter().character
                characterDetailTextTrial.text = randomCharacter().characterDetail
                characterImageView.image = randomCharacter().characterImage

} }
```

The code below shows the data on view but they are still not associated with each other:

```
  characterName.text = characterArray.randomElement()?.character
    characterDetailTextTrial.text =
characterArray.randomElement()?.characterDetail
    characterImageView.image = characterArray.randomElement()?.characterImage
```

I was able to solve the problem with the help of the code below:

```
if let randomProblem = problemArray.randomElement() {
                problemName.text = randomProblem.problem
                problemDetailTextTrial.text = randomProblem.problemDetail
 }
```

So to summarize, I didn't have to use random4arc to randomize the array instead I used randomElement() and get the values on the view.